# What does extended slice syntax actually do for negative steps?

Tags: python, list, slice, syntactic-sugar

The extended slice syntax in python has been explained to me as "`a[n:m:k] returns every kth element from n to m`".

This gives me a good idea what to expect when k is positive. But I'm lost on how to interpret `a[n:m:k]` for negative k. I know that `a[::-1]` reverses a, and that `a[::-k]` takes ever kth element of the reversed a.

But how is this a generalization of the definition for k positive? I'd like to know how `a[n:m:k]` is actually defined, so that (for example) I can understand why:

```
"abcd"[-1:0:-1] = "dcb"
```

Is `a[n:m:-k]` reversing the sequence a, then taking the elements with original indices starting from n and ending one before m or something? I don't think so, because this pattern doesn't fit other values of n and m I've tried. But I'm at a loss to figure out how this is actually defined, and searching has gotten me nowhere.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521798/what-are-the-default-slice-indices-in-python-really

Comment: This question aint a duplicate of "Explain Python's slice notation". This one asks specifics about negative step whereas the latter is generic to slice

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`[-1:0:-1]` means: start from the index `len(string)-1` and move up to `0`(not included) and take a step of `-1`(reverse).

So, the following indexes are fetched:

```
le-1, le-1-1, le-1-1-1  .... 1  # le is len(string)
```

example:

```
In [24]: strs = 'foobar'

In [25]: le = len(strs)

In [26]: strs[-1:0:-1]  # the first -1 is equivalent to len(strs)-1

Out[26]: 'raboo'

In [27]: strs[le-1:0:-1]   
Out[27]: 'raboo'
```

Comment: Thank you, this explanation was very clear to me. I was missing the recursive stepping and the fact that the endpoint is not inclusive.

Comment: Yups, the point that step creates a sequence makes this explanation "graspable"
i.e. str[-2:-6:-1] will result in following indices being selected
-2, -2-1=-3, -2-1-1=-4, all the way to -6 (excluded).
Eliciting with a string:
    >>> print ("07654321"[-2:-6:-1])
    2345

Comment: What value would you explicitly use for `i` and `j` in `strs[i:j:-1]` to reverse a string like `strs[::-1]`?

Comment: @AsadMoosvi `i` could be `None` or `len(strs)` and `j` could be `None`.

Comment: very nice thanks. 
Would 
strs[-2:-6] = 'ooba'
and
strs[-2:-6:-1] = 'aboo'

Answer (score 14):

The Python documentation ([here's the technical one](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings); the explanation for [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) is a bit easier to understand) is more correct than the simplified "every kth element" explanation. The slicing parameters are aptly named

```
slice[start:stop:step]
```

so the slice starts at the location defined by `start`, stops before the location `stop` is reached, and moves from one position to the next by `step` items.