# What is the purpose of using [:, :, ::-1] when reading images

Tags: python

I am following a tutorial to implement YoloV4 in the implementation the author has used this:

```
cv2.imread(os.path.join(self.folder_path, img_path))[:, :, ::-1]
```

Whats the point of the indexing at the end?

Comment: Do these answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517101/what-does-extended-slice-syntax-actually-do-for-negative-steps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: In this specific case, it's swapping between RGB and BGR order for the three components of each pixel.