# What is the default value of j in (i:j:k) numpy slicing?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have been reading the tutorial of numpy *i:j:k* slicing at [Scipy.org](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). After the second example, it says

> Assume *n* is the number of elements in the dimension being sliced. Then, if *i* is not given it defaults to 0 for *k > 0* and *n - 1* for *k < 0*. If *j* is not given it defaults to *n* for *k > 0* and **-1 for *k < 0***. If *k* is not given it defaults to 1.

However:

```python
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
>>> x[::-1]
array([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

If *j* is defaulted to -1, then `x[:-1:-1]` should be equivalent to `x[::-1]`, but

```python
>>> x[:-1:-1]
array([], dtype=int64)
>>> x[:-(len(x)+1):-1]
array([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

while

```python
>>> x[:-(len(x)+1):-1]
array([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

So the default value of *j* when *k < 0* should be *-(n+1)*. And according to [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521798/what-really-are-the-default-slice-indices-in-python), I believe the "official" default value of *j* when *k < 0* is `None`.

Am I misinterpreting the tutorial at SciPy.org?

Comment: I think there might have been a time when negative indices didn't count from the end of the array; the documentation line you're looking at might date from that time.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you! And by the way, thanks for reformatting my original post. I should definitely learn more about formatting on stackoverflow

Comment: For normal Python slices it defaults to `None` but I don't know about numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the first level of processing, the Python interpreter converts `::` notation into a `slice` object.  It is up to the `numpy.__getitem__` method to interpret those 3 numbers.

`[::-1]` is the same as `slice(None,None,-1)`.

As you note, `x[slice(None,None,-1)]` is not the same as `x[slice(None,-1,-1)]`.

I suspect that the `-1` in:

> `If j is not given it defaults to n for k > 0 and -1 for k < 0 .`

is not meant to be taken in that way.  Rather it has the usual meaning of -1, `the number before 0`.

In [285]: np.arange(10)[slice(5,0,-1)]
   Out[285]: array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])

`j` is interpreted as `iterate upto, but not including, this value`, with the direction of iteration determined by `k`.  So the `0` value is not included in this slice.

So how do you include the `0`?

```
In [287]: np.arange(10)[slice(5,-1,-1)]
Out[287]: array([], dtype=int32)
```

does not work because the `-1` is understood to be `n-1`, as in:

```
In [289]: np.arange(10)[slice(5,-7,-1)]
Out[289]: array([5, 4])
```

`None` is interpreted in a special way that lets us use:

```
In [286]: np.arange(10)[slice(5,None,-1)]
Out[286]: array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

This also works  (`10-11=-1` - the real `-1`)

```
In [291]: np.arange(10)[slice(5,-11,-1)]
Out[291]: array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

So there's a distinction between `-1` that means `before 0`, and `-1` that means `count from n`.  The documentation could be clear on this, but it's not wrong (if you use the right -1).