# How to explain the reverse of a sequence by slice notation a[::-1]

Tags: python, string, slice

From the [python.org tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)

> Slice indices have useful defaults; an omitted first index defaults to zero, an omitted second index defaults to the size of the string being sliced.

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> print(a[::-1])
olleh
```

As the tutorial says `a[::-1]` should equals to `a[0:5:-1]`

but `a[0:5:-1]` is empty as follows:

```
>>> print(len(a[0:5:-1]))
0
```

The question is not a duplicate of [explain-slice-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation). That question is about the general use of slicing in python.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre 
>>> print(a[5:0:-1])
olle

Comment: the docs don't mention the case of reverse iteration, yes. Good point.

Comment: How about `a[5::-1]`

Comment: This works - `a[5::-1]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre not sure this is a dupe. This question is really about the default values for the omitted slice indices in the cases of a negative step. I can't find it documented anywhere, but really, as the tutorial states, "Slice indices have useful defaults".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this dupe question is good (I upvoted), and the most upvoted answer of the "original" question doesn't answer, but the other one does in a way. I won't reopen because every time I reopened I had bad experiences. I'll let others do it if they want (you can vote!)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre whoops! Didn't realize that would take effect immediately... hmmm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga with great power comes great responsibility : you just found out that python gold badge can close/reopen singlehandedly :)

Comment: I'd personally call this language inconsistency since in the same line of reasoning `[0:5:1]` works just as intuition would suggest.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the docs are perhaps a little misleading on this, but the optional arguments of slicing if omitted are the same as using `None`:

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> a[::-1]
'olleh'
>>> a[None:None:-1]
'olleh'
```

You can see that these 2 above slices are identical from the CPython bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('a[::-1]') # or dis.dis('a[None:None:-1]')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (-1)
             12 BUILD_SLICE              3
             15 BINARY_SUBSCR
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

For a negative `step`, the substituted values for `None` are `len(a) - 1` for the `start` and `-len(a) - 1` for the `end`:

```
>>> a[len(a)-1:-len(a)-1:-1]
'olleh'
>>> a[4:-6:-1]
'olleh'
>>> a[-1:-6:-1]
'olleh'
```

This may help you visualize it:

```
    h  e  l  l  o   
    0  1  2  3  4  5
-6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
```

Comment: Can you show some referece for `the substituted values for None are len(a) - 1 for the start and -len(a) - 1 for the end`

Comment: @Alex "When k is negative, i and j are reduced to len(s) - 1 if they are greater. If i or j are omitted or None, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of k)" see point 5. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

Comment: @Alex Also see this relevant SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521798/what-are-the-default-slice-indices-in-python-really

Answer (score 3):

All it does is [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice). You pick. start stop and step so basically you're saying it should start at the beginning until the beginning but going backwards (-1).

If you do it with -2 it will skip letters:

```
>>> a[::-2]
'olh'
```

When doing `[0:5:-1]` your'e starting at the first letter and going back directly to 5 and thus it will stop. only if you try `[-1::-1]` will it correctly be able to go to the beginning by doing steps of negative 1.

**Edit to answer comments**

As pointed out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html) says

> an omitted second index defaults to the size of the string being
>   sliced.

Lets assume we have `str` with `len(str) = 5`. When you slice the string and omit, leave out, the second number it defaults to the length of the string being sliced, in this case - 5.
i.e `str[1:] == str[1:5]`, `str[2:] == str[2:5]`. The sentence refers to the length of the original object and not the newly sliced object.

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/2307698) is great

Comment: I'm sure OP knows what `a[::-1]` does.

Comment: The tutorial says "the omitted second index of a[::-1]  should be the size of string", so a[::-1] is equal to  a[:5:-1]. Why do you say " it should start at the beginning until the beginning"?
Do I misunderstand?

Comment: @IsaacDj tutorial link 
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html   
As follows `Slice indices have useful defaults; an omitted first index defaults to zero, an omitted second index defaults to the size of the string being sliced.`

Answer (score 3):

You are confused with the behavior of the stepping. To get the same result, what you can do is:

```
a[0:5][::-1]
'olleh'
```

Indeed, stepping wants to 'circle' around backwards in your case, but you are limiting it's movement by calling `a[0:5:-1]`.

Comment: I disagree with this explanation, `hello'[0:5:1]` will return `hello`, so why does -1 evaluate to `''`?

Comment: because stepping doesn't slice at all, just steps.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I personally think this is a language inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

`a[0:5:-1]` does not make much sense, since when you use this notation the indices mean: `a[start:end:step]`. When you use a negative step your end value needs to be at an "earlier" position than your start value.

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that the third slice argument, the `step`, is not presented in the part of the tutorial you quoted. That particular snippet assumes a positive step.

When you add in the possibility of a negative step, the behavior is actually pretty intuitive. An empty `start` parameter refers to whichever end of the sequence one would start at to step through the whole sequence in the direction indicated by the `step` value. In other words it refers to the lowest index (to count up) if you have a positive step, and the highest index (to count down) if you have a negative step. Likewise, an empty `end` parameter refers to whichever end of the sequence one would end up at after stepping through in the appropriate direction.

Answer (score 0):

The docs simply aren't correct about the default values as you've pointed out. However, they're consistent other than that minor error. You can view the docs I am referring to here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

### Note that the behavior is definitionaly correct according to the docs:

> The slice of s from i to j with step k is defined as the sequence of
>   items with index x = i + n*k such that 0 <= n < (j-i)/k. In other
>   words, the indices are i, i+k, i+2*k, i+3*k and so on, stopping when j
>   is reached (but never including j).

When you do:

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> y = a[0:5:-1]
```

we have that `i == 0`, `j == 5`, and `k == -1`. So we are grabbing items at index `x = i + n*k` for `n` starting at `0` and going up to `(j-i)/k`. However, observe that `(j-i)/k == (5-0)/-1 == -5`. There are no `n` such that `0 <= n < -5`, so you get the empty string:

```
>>> y
''
```

### Do `a[start:stop][::step]` when in doubt (it's almost always what we want)

It's almost always the case that when you pass a negative step to something like `x[start:stop:step]`, what you *want* to happen is for the sub selection to happen first, and then just go backwards by `step` (i.e. we usually want `x[start:stop][::step]`.

Futhermore, to add to the confusion, it happens to be the case that

```
x[start:stop:step] == x[start:stop][::step]
```

if `step > 0`. For example:

```
>>> x = list(range(10))
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> x[2:6:2]
[2, 4]
>>> x[2:6][::2]
[2, 4]
>>> x[1:10][::3]
[1, 4, 7]
>>> x[1:10:3]
[1, 4, 7]
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't hold when `step < 0`, even though it's tempting to think that it should.

After being burned by this a couple times, I realized it's just safer to always do the step clause *after* you perform the `start:stop` slice. So I *almost always* start with `y = x[start:stop][::step]`, at least when prototyping or creating a new module where correctness/readability is the primiary concern. This is less performant than doing a single slice, but if performance is an issue, then you can do the less readable:

```
y = x[start:stop:step] if step > 0 else x[stop:start:step]
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

For Python slicing for a **sequence[start:stop:step]**, have derived these rules:

1. start:stop  = start:stop:1
2. start:stop:(+ or -) step - It means when traversing skip N items in the sequence. However, (-) indicates backward traversal
3. Remember, position of last item in sequence is -1, and the one before than is -2, and so on..

**# start:stop: +step Rules**

1. Always traverse in forward
2. Always start from beginning of sequence as its a positive step ( forward )
3. Start at requested position, stop at requested position but exclude the item stop position
4. **Default start:** If start is not provided, start at 0
5. **Default stop:** if stop is not provided, it means until the end of the sequence **including** the last value
6. If item at stop position is not reachable (item is beyond the end of sequence traversal), slice does not return anything

**# start:stop:-step Rules**

1. Always traverse in reverse
2. If start position is provided, start from there, but traverse in reverse ( its a step back )
3. If stop is provided, stop traversing there but exclude this
4. **Default start:** If start position is not provided, start position is the last position of the sequence ( since negative traversal)
5. **Default stop:** If stop is not provided, it is the beginning of the list ( position 0)
6. If item at stop position is not reachable (item is beyond the end of sequence traversal), slice does not return anything