# Some confusion about Slice[::]

Tags: python

```
alphabet='abide'
>>>alphabet[-1::-1]
'ediba'
>>>alphabet[::-1]
'ediba'
```

Why did this two print out the same thing?
Shouldn't the second one be 'aedib'?

Comment: Why should it be 'aedib'? Why don't you trust the interpreter? ;) Basically, both slicing are equivalent for the interpreter.

Comment: Both slices are equivalent to `alphabet[None:None:-1]` or `alphabet[-1:-6:-1]`

Comment: A better dupe perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385999/how-to-explain-the-reverse-of-a-sequence-by-slice-notation-a-1

Answer (score 0):

```
alphabet[::-1]
```

Will reverse your string. Why? There is no value before the first colon, so it stats at the beginning index of the list. Then, still no value, so you go all the way to the end of the list. Third, you have `-1`, so you increment by -1, in other words you are going backwards.

It is equivalent to `alphabet[-1::-1]` since you just ask to start from the final character, which it already does.