# Python slicing explained

Tags: python

OK I understand the basics, but can someone explain code copied from Greg's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation):

```
a[1::-1]   # the first two items, reversed
a[:-3:-1]  # the last two items
a[-3::-1]  # everything except the last two items, reversed
```

To me the first one reads: slice from 2nd position to end, then reverse it.

The second one is slice from beginning to the -2 position then reverse it.

The third one is slice from -3rd position to end then reverse it.

Obviously I am wrong since they work as suggested, but can you please tell me why?

Comment: The direction (the `-1` in `a[1::-1] `) comes first and determines the direction. Reverse first, traverse second.

Comment: The question you referred to explains the 3rd parameter (step). Above the example prior to the one you shared.

Comment: Have you read the other answers under the one you link to? There are some very thorough explanations.

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385999/how-to-explain-the-reverse-of-a-sequence-by-slice-notation-a-1

Comment: You seem to be interpreting missing slice values as `beginning : end : 1`.  This is not true; with a negative step, the defaults are `end : beginning`.

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings

Comment: @jasonharper Not quite, with a negative step the defaults for a list called `a` like `a[::-1]` are `a[len(a)-1:-len(a)-1:-1]` https://stackoverflow.com/a/44389209/6260170

Comment: Sorry still don't get it. `a[:-3:-1] ` reverse the string, then start and stop are reversed? So my start is -3 end is blank? Is that right? Obviously not.

Comment: So we reverse the string, then does the first parameter refer to the start of the reversed string or the end of it? And why does it change, why not just have the-1 reverse the string and everything else stay the same?

Comment: Light bulb. Got it, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will probably be deleted but here goes:
First one is start at second position, head left as far as you can go.
Second is start at rightmost, head left ending before -3.
Third is start at-3 and head all the way to left.