# Index a string slice from it's end with a variable in python doesn't provide generic acces to last element

Tags: python, sequence, slice

This question is not about another way to solve the problem, but about the existence of a syntax to plug a hole. I know there are many other ways to do this, but it is not what I'm interested in.

In python, you can index sequences (strings, lists or tuples) from the end with negative index value, and you can slice them using ":" inside the square brackets. for an exemple, you can use `"123456789"[-4:-2]` to get `"67"`. You can even use a variable :

```
for i in range(-4, 0):
    print('"123456789"[-5:{}] yields "{}"'.format(i, "123456789"[-5:i]))
```

which will yield

```
"123456789"[-5:-4] yields "5"
"123456789"[-5:-3] yields "56"
"123456789"[-5:-2] yields "567"
"123456789"[-5:-1] yields "5678"
```

but what if you want to go up to the last position ? because `print(0, "123456789"[-5:0])` won't do :

```
for i in range(-4, 1):
    print('"123456789"[-5:{}] yields "{}"'.format(i, "123456789"[-5:i]))
```

which will yield

```
"123456789"[-5:-4] yields "5"
"123456789"[-5:-3] yields "56"
"123456789"[-5:-2] yields "567"
"123456789"[-5:-1] yields "5678"
"123456789"[-5:0] yields ""
```

One way to solve this might be to got to `None` instead of `0`, in order to emulate this code : `print(i, "123456789"[-5:])`

```
for r in range(-4, 0)), [None]:
    for i in r:
        print('"123456789"[-5:{}] yields "{}"'.format(i, "123456789"[-5:i]))
```

or

```
for i in [ x for r in [range(-4, 0)), [None] for x in r]:
    print('"123456789"[-5:{}] yields "{}"'.format(i, "123456789"[-5:i]))
```

which will yield

```
"123456789"[-5:-4] yields "5"
"123456789"[-5:-3] yields "56"
"123456789"[-5:-2] yields "567"
"123456789"[-5:-1] yields "5678"
"123456789"[-5:None] yields "56789"
```

but this is not a perfect solution, because `None` does not mean the last position, but the default value which will depend on the sign of the step and will lead to inconsistent results if step has a negative value:

```
for step in 1, -1:
    print("step={}".format(step))
    for r in [range(-7, -0), [None,]]:
        for i in r:
            print('"123456789"[-4:{}:{}] yields "{}"'.format(i, step, "123456789"[-4:i:step]))
```

will yield

```
step=1
"123456789"[-4:-7:1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-6:1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-5:1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-4:1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-3:1] yields "6"
"123456789"[-4:-2:1] yields "67"
"123456789"[-4:-1:1] yields "678"
"123456789"[-4:None:1] yields "6789"
step=-1
"123456789"[-4:-7:-1] yields "654"
"123456789"[-4:-6:-1] yields "65"
"123456789"[-4:-5:-1] yields "6"
"123456789"[-4:-4:-1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-3:-1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-2:-1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-1:-1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:None:-1] yields "654321"
```

is there another way to specify that my slice goes to the last position instead of the default position ?

Comment: Do you want to do it with a negative index?

Comment: You could use `len(s)` instead of None

Comment: "123456789"[-5:] yields "56789"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385999/how-to-explain-the-reverse-of-a-sequence-by-slice-notation-a-1

Comment: That's a good remark that if I can use `None`, I can also use `len(s)` (or any very big constant as @Salai Madhavaan mentioned in his answer).

Answer (score 1):

If the stop value in slice is greater than or equal to length of the string, It will be set to the length of the string by default.

`"123456789"[-5:len('123456789')]` also yields `'56789'`

Answer (score 1):

As mental excercise you can reverse string, grab needed slice and reverse it back. If you iterate over values :-):

```
in [1]: for i in range(1, 6):
...:     print('123456789'[::-1][:i][::-1])
...:
9
89
789
6789
56789
```

Comment: I suspect this won't be a very efficient solution but I like the idea :-)

Comment: yeah, it's mental exercise and its also beautifully symmetric :-)

Answer (score 0):

`None` is not the last item in the sequence. `None` is bound of sequence and when you change direction, you got expected result.

```
>>> s = "1234567890"
>>> s[-5::1]
'67890'
>>> s[-5::-1]
'654321'
>>> s[-5:len(s):1]
'67890'
>>> s[-5:len(s):-1]
''
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel Mesejo observed , if I'm ready to use the constant `None`, I can as well use len(s) or as @Salai Madhavan observed : any very large number, which would automagically be converted to len(s).

```
for step in 1, -1:
    print("step={}".format(step))
    for r in [range(-7, -0), [999999,]]:
        for i in r:
            print('"123456789"[-4:{}:{}] yields "{}"'.format(i, step, "123456789"[-4:i:step]))
```

will yield

```
step=1
"123456789"[-4:-7:1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-6:1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-5:1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-4:1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-3:1] yields "6"
"123456789"[-4:-2:1] yields "67"
"123456789"[-4:-1:1] yields "678"
"123456789"[-4:None:1] yields "6789"
step=-1
"123456789"[-4:-7:-1] yields "654"
"123456789"[-4:-6:-1] yields "65"
"123456789"[-4:-5:-1] yields "6"
"123456789"[-4:-4:-1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-3:-1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-2:-1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:-1:-1] yields ""
"123456789"[-4:999999:-1] yields ""
```