# why slice operator in below case doesn't work in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was watching a python video, and according to the logic of the slice operator by the instructor, one case was not not working.

```
step value can be either +ve or -ve
-----------------------------------------
if +ve then it should be forward direction (L to R)
if -ve then it should be backward direction(R to L)

if +ve forward direction from begin to end-1
if -ve backward direction from begin to end + 1

in forward direction
-------------------------------
default : begin : 0
default : end : length of string
default step : 1

in backward direction
---------------------------------
default begin : -1
default end : -(len(string) + 1)
```

I tried running the satement on python idle and got following result:

```
>>> x = '0123456789'
>>> x[2:-1:-1]
''
>>> x[2:0:-1]
'21'
```

According to the rules I should get result as `'210'` but I am getting `''`.

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: `x[2:-len(x)-1:-1]` >>> `210`

Comment: You can select an answer even after the question is closed

Answer (score 2):

The index `2:-1:-1` expands to `2:9:-1`. A negative start or stop index is **always** expanded to `len(sequence) + index`. `len('0123456789') + (-1)` is 9. You can't get from 2 to 9 in steps of -1, so the result is empty.

Instead, use `2::-1` an empty (or `None`) stop index means "grab it all". The default for an empty stop index when the strep size is negative is `-len(sequence) - 1`, which is also `-(len(sequence) + 1)`, to offset the fact that the stop index is *always exclusive*.

Comment: can you please let me know how it expands to 2:9:-1??

Comment: 10-1 = 9. 10 is len('0123456789').

Comment: Sorry, but i didnt get you, can you please let me know the generalised rule you applied to it?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to help you navigate the rules. This is a confusing topic that takes a while to grasp, no need to apologise. Let me know if you would like further clarification.

Comment: Thank you, but just one more doubt, how would you explain this? >>> x[-1:-6:-1]
'98765'

Comment: Same rules apply. `-1` is `9` (`len(x) - 1`) and `-6` is `4` (`len(x) - 6`). Now read it as `x[9:4:-1]`. Going down from `x[9]` to `x[5]` (stop index is exclusive) you get `'98765'`.

Comment: @Shivam. Intuitively, try to separate the negative start and stop (which get converted to real indices no matter what), and negative step, which is really negative and also controls the default limits.

Comment: thank you, Matthias and Mad Physicist, I got it.

Comment: one more , how you are going to explain this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385999/how-to-explain-the-reverse-of-a-sequence-by-slice-notation-a-1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44389209/2988730