Why am I getting an empty string if I use positive start index and negative stop and step index values?
I am trying to run this code snippet:
test="test"
print(test[3:-1:-1])

For the slicing, the start index should start from 3 which is inclusive and stop index should be -1 exclusive which means that it should be until 0 inclusive and the slicing is in reverse order as I mentioned the step to be -1, but the result am getting is empty string.
Why is this snippet which is test[3:-1:-1] not equivalent to test[3::-1] ?

it is not because test[3::-1] !=  test[3:-1:-1]

Essentially letter with index -1 is switched in the first case but in the second it's empty.

see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385999/how-to-explain-the-reverse-of-a-sequence-by-slice-notation-a-1

Note: print(test[3::-1] == test[3 : -len(test) -1 : -1]) as one equivalency.

I understand this way. The negative indexing is made more for the sake of convenience than for the sake of logical.
For instance, to denote the last characters: instead of counting the letters or mentioning test[len(test)-1], one can easily mention test[-1]. So the logic here is: if you start indexing the first character as 0, to denote the reverse representation, you should start counting from -1. If to add the first character also, if to add -1, logically there cant be two values with same index. So the previous character of the first letter becomes -5(for the string test)
So should follow any of these:
print(test[3:-5:-1])
print(test[-1:-5:-1])
print(test[3::-1])
print(test[::-1]) 

