# In list slicing, why the output of this code is an empty list? Ex. print(input_list[0: 4: -1])

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I am basically writing a code to take a list as an input and output the last item of the user given list items. This is the entire code:

```
     input_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
     list_Length = int(input())

     for i in range(list_Length):
         user_input = input()
         input_list.append(user_input)

     last_Before = list_Length - 2
     print(last_Before)
     print(input_list[: last_Before: -1])
```

My question is, instead of writing `print(input_list[: last_Before: -1])` at the last line, if I write `print(input_list[0: last_Before: -1])`, it gives me an empty string. WHY??!?!

Comment: can refer this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521798/what-are-the-default-slice-indices-really>

Answer (score 0):

That would be because the -1 in `input_list[::-1]` means that the list is going to be iterated in reverse order. If you write `input_list[0:last_Before:-1]` that means go from 0 to last_Before by subtracting -1 which prints an empty list since `0-1 = -1` and you cannot reach last_Before therefore, it prints an empty list. When you write `input_list[:last_Before:-1]` it prints the last element where the first index is implicitly `last_Before+1`. If you try printing `input_list[last_Before+1:last_Before:-1]` then it will print the same as `input_list[:last_Before:-1]`.